# Выбрасывается исключение java.util.NoSuchElementException при закрытии Scanner

Tags: java, исключения, scanner

Итак. Строилась программа по создании базы студентов. Есть класс Студент(Student.java):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Student {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastname;
        private int gradeLevel;
        private int balance;
        private String followingCourse;
        private String ID;
        private String[] courses;
        
        public Student() {
            System.out.println();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
            firstName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the last name: ");
            lastname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter grade level: ");
            gradeLevel = sc.nextInt();      // Сделать проверку на введеное число
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter balance: ");
            balance = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            // Сгенерировать ID
            //sc.close();
            
        }
        
        public void showInfo() {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("First name: " + firstName + " \\ ");
            System.out.println("Last name: " + lastname);
            System.out.println("Grade Level: " + gradeLevel);
            System.out.println("ID: " + ID);
            System.out.println("Balance: " + balance);
            System.out.println("followng courses: ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    
    }
```

Есть класс Базы(DataBase.java):

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
        
        public class DataBase {
            private Student[] StudentBase;          // Общая база всех студентов
            private int studentCount = 0;           // Количество студентов
                
            private Student[] History;
            private Student[] Math;
            private Student[] English;
            private Student[] Chemistry;
            private Student[] CompScience;
            
            public DataBase() { StudentBase = new Student[0]; }         // создание базы данных
            
            /* Добавить студентов в базу */
            public void AddStudents() {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("How many students should be added: ");
                int num = scan.nextInt();
                if(StudentBase.length == 0) {
                    StudentBase = new Student[num];
                }else {
                    // Перепись базы
                    Student[] temp = new Student[studentCount+num];
                    for(int i = 0; i < StudentBase.length; i++)
                        temp[i] = StudentBase[i];
                    StudentBase = temp;
                }       
                // Добавление студентов     // Проблема добавления студентов
                for(int i = studentCount; i <studentCount + num; i++) {
                    StudentBase[i] = new Student();
                }
                studentCount += num;        // Прибавим количество студентов в конце 
                scan.close();
            }
            
            /* Методы для показа информации */
            public void showInfo() {
                for(int i = 0; i < StudentBase.length; i++) {
                    StudentBase[i].showInfo();
                }
            }
            
            /* Добавить массивы разынх курсов */
            /* Метод для поступления на курс */
        }
```

И происходит выполнение программы:

```
public class DatabaseApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
        dataBase.AddStudents();
        dataBase.showInfo();
        dataBase.AddStudents();
    }
}
```

При добавлении студентов `dataBase.AddStudents();` в методе класса DataBase открывается сканер `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)`, после чего, он закрывается: `scan.close();`. И когда вызывается повторно метод AddStudents(): `dataBase.AddStudents();` выбрасывается исключение `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. Причем, если убрать строчку `scan.close();` в классе DataBase, исключение не выбрасывается.
**Как это связано с закрытием Scanner, и как исправить эту ошибку?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что метод `Scanner.close` закрывает тот `InputStream`, который ему передали.

Это значит, что после первого вызова `AddStudents` вы закрываете `System.in`, а значит последующие попытки чтения из него приведут к ошибке, что, собственно, и просходит.

В этом случае правильно (и проще всего тоже) не закрывать scanner, так как у вас всегда передается `System.in`, а этот поток вообще закрывать не имеет смысла.

В некоторых случаях у вас может быть универсальный код со `Scanner`, то есть такой, который не знает какой именно ему `InputStream` передается, но он принимает его во владение. Под владением я имею ввиду то, что этот код является ответственным за закрытие переданного `InputStream`. И так как он не знает, передан ему поток ввода созданный из файла (который можно и должно закрывать) или `System.in`, то тут возникает проблема.

Ее решают тем, что передают не непосредственно `System.in`, а заворачивают его в декоратор для `InputStream`, который игнорирует вызов метода `close`. В JDK такого нету (по крайней мере до версии 8 точно не было, может сейчас изменилось что-то), но есть в [apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html).