# Можете помочь с задачей на Java?

Tags: java, scanner, bool

Четных больше
Даны 3 целых числа. Требуется определить, есть ли среди этих чисел хотя бы два четных.

Входные данные
Во входном потоке в единственной строке через пробел записаны 3 целых числа (−109≤x≤109).

Выходные данные
Выведите true, если среди данных чисел есть хотя бы два четных, или false в противном случае.

Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nameclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double a = sc.nextDouble();
double b = sc.nextDouble();
double c = sc.nextDouble();
boolean v = (a/2 || b/2 || c/2);
System.out.print(v);

}

}
```

Comment: не забудте вызвать `close` у сканера

Comment: @Olegator36, вызов `close` для сканера, открытого на системном потоке ввода, [не имеет смысла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1313521/386633), так как будет закрыт сам этот поток.

Comment: Integer.toBinaryString(x).endsWith("0");  -  если  ноль  четно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо nextdouble стоит использовать nextInt, не так ли?

Сложите

```
a&1+b&1+c&1
```

и посмотрите на результат

```
boolean v = ((a&1)+(b&1)+(c&1)) < 2;
System.out.print(v);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139586/discussion-on-answer-by-mbo------java).

Answer (score 0):

```
int  x1 = 14;
int  x2 = -28;
int  x3 = 97;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x1).endsWith("0")
||Integer.toBinaryString(x3).endsWith("0") 
||Integer.toBinaryString(x3).endsWith("0"));
```

но думаю это не оптимальный путь

Answer (score 0):

При помощи функциональных интерфейсов можно гибко фильтровать как тебе нужно.

```
    public class FindTwoEvenNumbers {
    public static boolean filterNumbers(List<Integer> inventory, NumberPredicate predicate) {
        boolean b = false;
        for (Integer i : inventory) {
            if (predicate.test(i)) {
                b = true;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static class NumbersEven implements NumberPredicate {
        int count;
        @Override
        public boolean test(Integer integer) {
            if (integer % 2 == 0) {
                count++;
            }
            return count >= 2;
        }
    }

    public interface NumberPredicate{
        boolean test(Integer integer);
    }
}
```

И тестируем:

```
class FindTwoEvenNumbersTest {

    @Test
    void filterNumbers() {
        assertTrue(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4), new NumbersEven()));
        assertTrue(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(12, 20, 4), new NumbersEven()));
        assertTrue(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(3, 18, 2), new NumbersEven()));

        assertFalse(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(3, 5, 13), new NumbersEven()));
        assertFalse(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 17), new NumbersEven()));
        assertFalse(FindTwoEvenNumbers.filterNumbers(Arrays.asList(2, 13, 23), new NumbersEven()));
    }
}
```

Если хочешь запустить в методе main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lists = Arrays.asList(2, 5, 10);
        System.out.println(filterNumbers(lists, new NumbersEven()));
    }
```