# Выдаёт ошибку при использовании Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Всем привет. При попытке ввода элементов в массив выдаёт ошибку - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Scanner.nextInt()" because "Main.scn" is null
at Main.inputElements(Main.java:35)
at Main.main(Main.java:24)
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема

Код:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner scn;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Cпосіб заповнення" +
                "\n1. Введення з клавіатури. " +
                "\n2. Рандом.");
        int chose = scn.nextInt();
        switch (chose){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Розмір масиву: ");
                int size;
                try {
                    size = scn.nextInt(); //ввод размера массива
                } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
                   throw new InputMismatchException("Ввод только чисел");
                }
                int[] array = new int[size];
                inputElements(array);
                System.out.println(array);
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
        }
    }
    private static void inputElements(int[] array){
        System.out.println("Элементы массива:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           array[i] = scn.nextInt(); //ввод элементов массива
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправил несколько ваших ошибок и пометил их комментариями.

1. Вы когда выводите массив на экран - у вас не получится это сделать, так как у объекта массив целых чисел не переопределен метод toString. Правильнее пользоваться статическим классом Arrays.
2. Вы когда считываете целое число сканером, вы кроме цифры, например "4" передаете еще и символ перевода строки "\n" когда нажимаете Enter. метод nextInt() съедает цифру, но при этом ничего не делает с символом перевода строки. И именно этот символ "лезет" в ваш следующий метод scn.nextInt(). Java видит что это не инт и выбрасывает исключение. Выход: после каждой вычитки целого значения использовать команду scn.nextLine();  она "съест" лишний символ перевода строки, и продолжится корректное выполнение программы.
3. Сканнер нужно закрывать scanner.close(). **upd. НЕ НУЖНО!!! (Объяснение в комментариях)**

   ```
    public class Main {
    private final static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Cпосіб заповнення" +
                "\n1. Введення з клавіатури. " +
                "\n2. Рандом.");

        int chose = scn.nextInt();
        scn.nextLine();        /// сброс сканера
        switch (chose) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Розмір масиву: ");
                int size;
                try {
                    size = scn.nextInt();
                    scn.nextLine();         //// сброс сканера
                    //ввод размера массива
                } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException("Ввод только чисел");
                }
                int[] array = new int[size];
                inputElements(array);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // не правильный вывод на экран массива
                //System.out.println(array);
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
        }
        scn.close();        //// Сканнер нужно закрывать
    }

    private static void inputElements(int[] array) {

        System.out.println("Элементы массива:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            array[i] = scn.nextInt();
            scn.nextLine();//ввод элементов массива
        }

    }
   ```

   }

Comment: Возможно ли сделать без объявления сканнера в каждом методе?

Comment: @wavy_   Да, конечно. Подправил ответ - в нем используется один объект сканнера

Comment: @had0uken, вызов close для сканера, открытого на системном потоке ввода `System.in`, [не имеет смысла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1313521/386633), так как будет закрыт сам этот поток.  Даже если бы сканер был открыт для файла или хотя бы строки, тогда следовало бы использовать `try-with-resources`.

Comment: И основная ошибка автора - в некорректной инициализации экземпляра сканера, _локального_ для метода `main`, соответственно в другом методе статическое поле осталось непроинициализированным

Comment: @NowhereMan спасибо! Открыл почитал как это происходит под капотом. Действительно не имеет смысла. Прям вообще никакого.

Comment: @had0uken, спасибо за ответ